# The physics in "Come Back to the Killing Ground, Alice, My Love"

Tags: come-back-to-the-killing-ground

I have trouble understanding the physics in "Come Back to the Killing Ground, Alice, My Love" written by Roger Zelazny. It talked about an assassin fighting against a singularity with a super-string. I know the theory of relativity, but the plot is still confusing.

Could you please explain the scientific idea to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not physics, they're magic coated with a layer of physics jargon.  But they are based on real ideas from physics.

(This is a classic Zelazny technique, to take myth and put it in the real world, but not to make the myth mundane, but to make the real world mythical.)

To the physics: Zelazny uses two pieces of *highly speculative* (*really* highly speculative) physics as props: Super (cosmological) strings and singularities. (And please forgive me -- everything I write here is an oversimplification.)

A super string is a concept which some of our theories imply might exist. *No cosmological string has ever been observed* and their (hypothetical) properties are such that we probably should have observed them if they existed anywhere in the observable universe.

In modern physics, vacuums are busy places -- space without *anything* in it is in principle impossible in modern physics -- and the vacuum has properties which can (and have) been measured.  (Now we move from "pretty solid physics" to "intelligent speculation well beyond the evidence".)  There can be different vacuums (called "vacuum states") with different properties.  It turns out that many of those different vacuums are unstable and can decay to a lower-energy vacuum.

Current theory doesn't have an explanation why the universe is in the specific vacuum state it is in -- as far as we can tell, during the very earliest times of the Big Bang, the vacuum could have been formed in pretty much any state.  If so, as the universe cools, the vacuum state may decay to a lower-energy state. But this doesn't happen instantaneously or everywhere at once, but must start at some point in spacetime and propagate outwards at the speed of light.  But somewhere else, at more or less the "same time", the vacuum may decay to a different lower-energy state and that also propagates.  The result can be that different parts of spacetime may be in different vacuum states. The boundaries where these different states abut one another form what are called "topological defects" in space-time and cosmological strings are one type.

Making reasonable extrapolations from what we're confident of, we can compute the properties of these cosmological strings and they are pretty extreme.  They'd make a great weapon. If they existed. If they could be safely approached. If they could be handled. If their greater-than-stellar mass allowed them to be moved around.

(BTW, it's worth noting that this type of string has nothing at all to do with the strings of particle physics.  Though not everyone agrees.  But, then, how can anyone definitively prove that one hypothetical (and not completely understood) thing is different from another?)

Singularities are a mathematical flaw in General Relativity which inevitably form at the center of a Black Hole, and are points where the laws of physics break down and predictability ends.  This is generally considered to be a Bad Thing for a physical theory, and indicates that the theory is flawed and that whatever is at the center of a Black Hole, we can't presently predict what it is. (This is the view of most professionals in GR.)

Nonetheless, General Relativity does an amazing job of explaining everything we can observe. (Singularities appear to be unobservable in principle -- at any rate, no object we have yet detected could contain a "naked singularity").  So we have two options: Assume GR is right and singularities are real, or conclude that there is a more general theory of gravity which is the same as GR in the regions of space-time we can observe, but which differs in the so-far unobservable regions in which singularities lurk. This is one of the major motivations of the string theory of current particle physics.

So, we have cosmological strings vs singularities, two bits of speculation grounded in physics which are employed to provide the props and scenery for a story.

Comment: I didn't know cosmic strings before. I thought the string in the story came from the string theory, but didn't make sense. Now I see the intended idea. Thank you!

Comment: Some people think they *are* the same things!  But I believe that's very much a minority view. (The ironic bit is that the strings of particle physics *may* eventually (if they prove to be a good theory) explain the singularities of General Relativity!)